# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream to parse is null

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

Please help me to know what is wrong with my code.[I tried from this link for Sample.](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364926/Using-The-Digester-Component) OS : Windows 7

**Code 1 :**

```
 DigestStudents ds = (DigestStudents) digester.parse(this.getClass()
                            .getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("leo/test/digester/student/student.xml"));
```

**Exception 1:**

```
true:isFile:isHidden:false    
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream to parse is null
at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1621)
at leo.test.digester.student.DigestStudents.digest(DigestStudents.java:41)
at leo.test.digester.student.DigestStudents.main(DigestStudents.java:16)
```

**Code 2 :**

```
 File f = new File ("D:/workspace/RD_Axway/src/leo/test/digester/student/student.xml");
 System.out.println(f.isFile()+":isFile:isHidden:"+f.isHidden());
 DigestStudents ds = (DigestStudents) digester.parse(f);
```

**Exception 2:**

```
true:isFile:isHidden:false
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:790)
    at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1588)
    at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1557)
    at leo.test.digester.student.DigestStudents.digest(DigestStudents.java:41)
    at leo.test.digester.student.DigestStudents.main(DigestStudents.java:16)
```

**Student.java**

```
package leo.test.digester.student;

public class Student {
private String name;
private String course;

public Student() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(String newCourse) {
    course = newCourse;
}
public String toString() {
    return("Name="+this.name + " & Course=" +  this.course);
}
}
```

**student.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<students>
        <student>
                <name>Java Boy</name>
                <course>JSP</course>
        </student>
        <student>
                <name>Java Girl</name>
                <course>EJB</course>
        </student>
</students>
```

**DigestStudents.java**

```
package leo.test.digester.student;

import java.util.Vector;
import org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester;

public class DigestStudents {
    Vector students;

    public DigestStudents() {
        students= new Vector();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DigestStudents digestStudents = new DigestStudents();
        digestStudents.digest();
    }

    private void digest() {
        try {
            Digester digester = new Digester();
            //Push the current object onto the stack
            digester.push(this);

            //Creates a new instance of the Student class
            digester.addObjectCreate( "students/student", Student.class );

            //Uses setName method of the Student instance
            //Uses tag name as the property name
            digester.addBeanPropertySetter( "students/student/name");

            //Uses setCourse method of the Student instance
            //Explicitly specify property name as 'course'
            digester.addBeanPropertySetter( "students/student/course", "course" );

            //Move to next student
            digester.addSetNext( "students/student", "addStudent" );

             File f = new File ("D:/workspace/RD_Axway/src/leo/test/digester/student/student.xml");
             System.out.println(f.isFile()+":isFile:isHidden:"+f.isHidden());


            DigestStudents ds = (DigestStudents) digester.parse(this.getClass()
                                .getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("D:/workspace/RD_Axway/src/leo/test/digester/student/student.xml"));

            //Print the contents of the Vector
            System.out.println("Students Vector "+ds.students);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addStudent( Student stud ) {
        //Add a new Student instance to the Vector
        students.add( stud );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi All Thanks for all your Help.But Exact problem is JAR Mismatch.Finally tried with only four jars now it works.JARs common-collections-2.1.1.jar
common-logging-1.0.4.jar
common-beanutils-1.6.1.jar
common-digester3.3.0.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()` is able to locate files relative to the "**root**" of the classpath. You need to replace this line:

```
 DigestStudents ds = (DigestStudents) digester.parse(this.getClass()
                       .getClassLoader()
                       .getResourceAsStream("D:/workspace/RD_Axway/src/leo/test/digester/student/student.xml"));
```

With

```
 DigestStudents ds = (DigestStudents) digester.parse(this.getClass()
                       .getClassLoader()
                       .getResourceAsStream("leo/test/digester/student/student.xml"));
```

Comment: if the `student.xml` file exists in your classpath at `leo/test/digester/student/` then it should works!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but am using Eclipse IDE I tried to put the file in a location and checked the file null or not then passed the file object to digester , getting some other exception.Please check updated Question.

Comment: In eclipse, right click your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source. What is your 'default output folder'? `bin/classes`?

Comment: /RD_Axway. there also file available

Comment: OK, is there any `leo/test/digester/student/student.xml` inside `/RD_Axway`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this line is problematic:

`DigestStudents ds = (DigestStudents) digester.parse(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("D:/workspace/RD_Axway/src/leo/test/digester/student/student.xml"));`

The resource cannot be found, thus null is being returned.

Comment: Please check my Exception Trace there file is available !

Comment: Easy with the '!' :) Using absolute path in getResourceAsStream, correct me if I am wrong, is relative to the class path root. I suggest you put it in your src folder for starters and work your way out

Comment: OR you can opt to use a FileInputStream maybe? If ever you want to stick with the absolute file path

Comment: Please check my updated question even if send the File Object ,it is not working .

Answer (score 1):

ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream looks for files in your classpath. 
Change your getResourceAsStream to:

```
.getResourceAsStream("student.xml"));
```

Make sure that you specify the path

```
D:/workspace/RD_Axway/src/leo/test/digester/student/
```

in your classpath and then re-compile and run it again.

Comment: Can you show what's your classpath? Either its in an environment variable or you're defining it when you run in commandline like java -cp ...

Comment: Am using Eclipse IDE.Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Both `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` work on URIs relative to the classpath.

You'll need to modify the path to be something along the lines of

```
getResourceAsStream("/leo/test/digester/student/student.xml");
```

Comment: Then try without the preceding '/'. If studen.xml is in the runtime classpath under the directory leo/test/digester/student/ it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of getting object that loaded our class is to be able to get resources independently from current system setup, from current absolute paths.
You get null in `getResourceAsStream` because file couldn't be found. Just make path to `student.xml` relative, or absolute to classpath as Kayaman suggested.

```
this.getClass()
.getClassLoader()
.getResourceAsStream("path/to/file/student.xml")
```

You get file by `classLoader.getResourceAsStream` with the same path search order that was used to load current class. Please see javadoc for getResource:

> java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String name)
>
> Finds the resource with the given name. A resource is some data
>   (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way
>   that is independent of the location of the code.
>
> The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies
>   the resource.
>
> This method will first search the parent class loader for the
>   resource; if the parent is null the path of the class loader built-in
>   to the virtual machine is searched. That failing, this method will
>   invoke findResource(String) to find the resource.

Thanks to this generalization, code is more portable, doesn't matter if you are on Windows or Linux, or even on some distributed system. More on loading classes and possible sources: [java.lang.ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)

Answer (score 0):

Either place the file in current folder or uri format.

```
//placing the xml file in the current java file folder(which is not goog way of coding.

DigesterTest ds = (DigesterTest) digest.parse(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
             "test.xml"));
DigesterTest ds = (DigesterTest) digest.parse("file://exact location of the file");
//created a xml folder under java project 
DigesterTest ds = (DigesterTest) digest.parse(new File("xml/test.xml"));
```